# How to use netTcpBinding and netMsmqBinding together?

Tags: wcf, wcf-binding

```
I am trying to use both tcp as well as msmq but it gives an error msmq doesn't support dual binding or it's not properly configured, how to solve this issue? 
I have created two end points. 

I tried to do something like this 



  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <netTcpBinding>
        <binding name="Binding_Config" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00" openTimeout="00:02:30">
          <security mode="None">
            <transport clientCredentialType ="None" protectionLevel="None"></transport>
            <message clientCredentialType="None"/>
          </security>
        </binding>
      </netTcpBinding>

      <netMsmqBinding>
        <binding name="ServiceBinding" durable="true" exactlyOnce="true" useActiveDirectory="false" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00" openTimeout="00:02:30" >
          <security mode="None">
            <transport
               msmqAuthenticationMode="None"
               msmqProtectionLevel="None"

              />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </netMsmqBinding>
    </bindings>

    <services>
      <service name="WCFLib.SignalService"
        behaviorConfiguration = "SignalServiceMEXBehavior">
        <endpoint address ="TradeSignalService"
        binding="netTcpBinding"
        contract="TradeServiceLib.ITradeSignalService" bindingConfiguration="Binding_Config"/>
        <!-- Enable the MEX endpoint -->

        <!-- Need to add this so MEX knows the address of our service -->


        <endpoint  address="net.msmq://localhost/private/FirstQueue" binding="netMsmqBinding" contract="TradeServiceLib.ITradeSignalService" bindingConfiguration="ServiceBinding"/>
        <!--<endpoint address="mex" binding="netTcpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>-->


        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress ="http://192.168.1.125:2344"/>
            <add baseAddress ="net.tcp://192.168.1.125:2348"/>
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
    <!-- A behavior definition for MEX -->
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="SignalServiceMEXBehavior" >
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>

  <connectionStrings>
    <clear />

  </connectionStrings>

</configuration>

I am not sure where I am wrong.
```

I don't know why but this site needs more text from me so typing this line, please ignore this I don't know why but this site needs more text from me so typing this line, please ignore this I don't know why but this site needs more text from me so typing this line, please ignore this I don't know why but this site needs more text from me so typing this line, please ignore this I don't know why but this site needs more text from me so typing this line, please ignore this

Comment: you should share your code or web.config in order to someone help you.

Comment: Okay, thanks for advice.

Answer (score 0):

Those two bindings are very different. You need two endpoints for the same service exposed at different addresses and set up with different bindings.

See this [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751515.aspx) article for more information on this.

As an example:

```
<service 
    name="Microsoft.ServiceModel.Samples.CalculatorService"
    behaviorConfiguration="CalculatorServiceBehavior">
  <!-- This endpoint is exposed at the base address provided by host:
       http://localhost/servicemodelsamples/service.svc  -->
  <endpoint address=""
            binding="basicHttpBinding"
            contract="Microsoft.ServiceModel.Samples.ICalculator" />
  <!-- secure endpoint exposed at {base address}/secure:
       http://localhost/servicemodelsamples/service.svc/secure -->
  <endpoint address="secure"
            binding="wsHttpBinding"
            contract="Microsoft.ServiceModel.Samples.ICalculator" />
  ...
</service>
```

Comment: I am trying to do same but I am messing up somewhere with duplex thing.

Comment: Should I post that client config as well?